# Why is spring boot not finding my beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-bean

i have following error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.yyy.zzz.xxx.service.ControlService required a bean of type 'com.yyy.zzz.xxx.service.composeXML.ComposeCounterService' that could not be found.
```

Usually this is because i forget to annotate either the Service or
the interface, but i've been looking classes the whole morning and cant find
any missing annotations..

interface at this point is just:

```
@Component
public interface ComposeCounterService {
CLASSX init(List<YYY> owners) throws JAXBException;
}
```

and implimenting service is as follows, and contains init() method if that matters in this case.

```
@Service
public class ComposeCounterImpl implements ComposeCounterService {
/*** loots of code
}
```

and ApplicationConfig file is located one level above the service package. marked xxx in this post.

It contains the following package scan:

```
@SpringBootApplication
scanBasePackages = {"com.yyy.zzz.xxx")
```

i also tried it with array of scans like:

```
scanBasePackages = {"com.yyy.zzz.xxx", "com.yyy.zzz.xxx.service.composeXML"})
```

and without the composeXML after .service
None of these works.

im pretty sure im missing something here, please send help.

EDIT:
injecting style:

```
private final ComposeCounterService composeCounterService;

public ControlService(ComposeCounterService composeCounterService) {
    this.composeCounterService = composeCounterService;
}
```

Comment: Show how you Autowire it. Btw you don't need Component annotation on service, and you don't need scanBasePackages, SpringBoot automatically scan for basePackage.

Comment: Added. Also you mean i dont need the "at"Service, since i have "at"Component on the interface which the service impliments? I know i dont need scanBasePackages but at this point i added it to be sure, but good to know it should work without! @Moler

Comment: Sorry I meant, you don't need component it at your interface. You only need Service annotation on your ComposeCounterImpl.

Comment: Check, nice to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the wrong import is:

```
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;
```

correct is:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
```

If you just let your IDE suggest the import and press enter without reading which one it adds, this is the result.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem but my import is correct

Answer (score 2):

I am an absolute idiot...

People, always check your imports...
I even overlooked this and pasted only the code that would not solve the problem...

I had wrong import for @service annotation.. and thats the root cause of the problem.
only took several hours of very angry debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the package `com.yyy.zzz.xxx.service` in your `scanBasePackages` properties as your `ControlService` lies in this package.

Try this and let me know if you get any other issue

**--Edit**

Remove `@Component` from your `interface ComposeCounterService` (as interface never gets initialized)

Now give the bean name to your Service class as :

```
@Service("composeCounterImpl")
public class ComposeCounterImpl implements ComposeCounterService {
/*** loots of code
}
```

Now define your constructor as:

```
@Autowired
public ControlService(@Qualifier("composeCounterImpl") ComposeCounterService composeCounterService) {
    this.composeCounterService = composeCounterService;
}
```

P.S: Make sure that all the pacakges are available in the component scan

Comment: It says in the question i already tried that. Tried again, still dosent work :(

Comment: Does the exception change after adding this?

Comment: Injection type is already added to question. beyond that it's only composeCounterService.init(owners);

Comment: In ControlService? that didnt help

Comment: Just now I noticed that ComposeCounterService  is an interface and not a class, have edited the code, please try now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `@Autowired` on ComposeCounterService field?

If so; maybe can try using `@ComponentScan` above `@SpringBootApplication`

Documentation Here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: i dont use Autowire, and adding ComponenScan didnt help :(

Comment: Ah I see..

Is there a reason why you're not using `@Autowired` to inject the Spring Bean?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now, where a specific bean couldn't be found when testing. In my case the problem was a `@WebMvcTest`-annotation (wrapped inside a custom one, so I missed it). That annotation prevents SpringBoot from loading any components/beans except for those included here:

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent, Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

You can force the loading of specific beans using the `@Import`-annotation like so:

```
@Import({ YourFirstBean.class, ThatOtherBean.class })
```